# Placeholder for hardware reserved registers in struct

Tags: c, hardware

i have a struct which represents a set of hardware registers. Here, some parts are reserved and must neither be written nor read. Is there a placeholder or something similar instead of using an obvious variable naming?

```
typedef volatile struct RegisterStruct
{
  uint8 BDH;
  uint8 BDL;
  ...
  uint8 IR;
  uint8 RESERVED0; // this area should not be accessed
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wrap them in another struct (so they are `RegisterStruct.RESERVED.r01`), or allocate them as an int array (`uint8 RESERVED[12]`).

Answer (score 3):

Obvious naming would be the right thing to use, as there's no "reserved" feature in C.

You can use arrays of byte-sized integers to correctly pad to the right length:

```
typedef volatile struct RegisterStruct
{
  uint8_t BDH;
  uint8_t BDL;
  uint8_t IR;
  uint8_t __RESERVED[num_of_reserved_bytes]; // this area should not be accessed
  uint8_t NEXT_REGISTER_NAME;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using structs for register mapping in general (or similarly, for data communication protocol mapping), is that a struct may contain padding bytes anywhere.

If you use a struct (or union) for such purposes, you have to ensure that padding is disabled, by adding a line like for example

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(RegisterStruct) == sizeof(uint8_t)*4, "Padding detected");
```

This will prevent padding bugs, as it will block structs with padding from compiling.

Unfortunately, you cannot disable struct padding in a portable manner; most of the time you *don't* want to disable it because it will make the programs slower at best, in the worst case you'll get hardware exceptions for misaligned access, all depending on CPU.

The most common non-standard extension to disable padding is `#pragma pack(1)`, but it is non-standard and non-portable.

In my opinion, the best way to avoid all such problems is to avoid structs entirely for the actual mapping. Instead, just declare everything as plain volatile variables. (Or by using macros, which is unfortunately the only way you can map something to a specific memory location in standard C).

And when you have gotten that far, there's no need to use any "reserved" place holders. Simply don't map anything to those reserved memory locations.

There's actually really no sound reason why you would want to have a number of hardware registers in a struct, even though it is for some reason mighty popular to do so among embedded compilers. You'll find that register maps written for such compilers are unreadable and also extremely non-standard.

For communication protocols it makes more sense to have structs, but then you would typically write serialize/de-serialize routines to fill up the struct.

Comment: You are right. But the usage of structs for this purpose has at least one advantage. If you develop a driver for a module (e.g. UART) with a specific register mapping, you can distinguish between different microcontrollers having this module by only changing the address the struct is pointing at.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in C to declare a placeholder/hole without a name in a structure or something with a name that is unreadable (const could help but with write protection only). And I don't see anything in gcc's extensions that could help here.

But you could additionally scramble the name by using the preprocessor, e.g.:

```
#define GLUE(X,Y,Z) X ## Y ## Z
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define SCRAMBLE(X) GLUE(X,_,__COUNTER__)
#else
#define SCRAMBLE(X) GLUE(X,_,__LINE__)
#endif

typedef volatile struct
{
  uint8 BDH;
  uint8 BDL;
//  ...
  uint8 IR;
  uint8 SCRAMBLE(RESERVED0);
//  ...
} RegisterStruct;
```

Comment: Good idea, but i do not want to obfuscate my code ;-)

Comment: @m47h Well, you do. :)